# Model selection & Selecting the number of active components in Bayesian Gaussian Mixture Models

Tags: scikit-learn, bayesian, mixture-model

I have generated 2 groups of 1-D data points which are visually clearly separable and I want to use a Bayesian Gaussian Mixture Model (BGMM) to ideally recover 2 clusters.

Since BGMMs maximize a lower bound on the model evidence (ELBO) and given that the ELBO is supposed to combine notions of accuracy and complexity, I would expect more complex models to be penalized.

However, when running Grid Search over the number of clusters, I often get a solution with more than 2 clusters. More specifically, I often get the maximal number of clusters on my grid search. In the example below, I would expect the best model to define 2 clusters. Instead, the best models defines 4 but assigns minimal weights to 2 out of 4 clusters.
I am really surprised, since 2 out of 4 clusters are therefore adding little information and this more complex model still gets selected as the best model.

Why is the BGMM then picking 4 clusters for the best model?

If this is indeed the behavior a BGMM should show, how can I then assess how many active components I actually have in my model? Visually? By defining an arbitrary threshold on the weights?

I have added the code to reproduce my example below.

[image]

```
# Import statements
import itertools
import multiprocessing

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from sklearn.mixture import BayesianGaussianMixture
from sklearn.utils import shuffle


def fitmodel(x, params):
  '''
  Instantiates and fits Bayesian GMM
  Used in the parallel for loop
  '''
  # Gaussian mixture model
  clf = BayesianGaussianMixture(**params)
  # Fit
  clf = clf.fit(x, y=None)
  return clf

def plot_results(X, means, covariances, title):
    
  plt.plot(X, np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=len(X)),'o', alpha=0.1, color='cornflowerblue', label='data points')
  for i, (mean, covar) in enumerate(zip(
    means, covariances)):
    # Get normal PDF
    n_sd = 2.5
    x = np.linspace(mean - n_sd*covar, mean + n_sd*covar, 300)
    x = x.ravel()
    y = stats.norm.pdf(x, mean, covar).ravel()
    if i == 0:
      label = 'Component PDF'
    else:
      label = None
    plt.plot(x, y, color='darkorange', label=label)
  plt.yticks(())
  plt.title(title)

# Generate data
g1 = np.random.uniform(low=-1.5, high=-1, size=(1,100))
g2 = np.random.uniform(low=1.5, high=1, size=(1,100))
X  = np.append(g1, g2)

# Shuffle data
X = shuffle(X)
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)

# Define parameters for grid search
parameters = {
  'n_components': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'weight_concentration_prior_type':['dirichlet_distribution']
}

# Create permutations of parameter settings
keys, values = zip(*parameters.items())
param_grid = [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in itertools.product(*values)]

# Run GridSearch using parallel for loop
list_clf = [None] * len(param_grid)
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
list_clf = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(fitmodel)(X, params) for params in param_grid)

# Print best model (based on lower bound on model evidence)
lower_bounds = [x.lower_bound_ for x in list_clf] # Extract lower bounds on model evidence
idx = int(np.where(lower_bounds == np.max(lower_bounds))[0]) # Find best model

best_estimator = list_clf[idx]
print(f'Parameter setting of best model: {param_grid[idx]}')
print(f'Components weights: {best_estimator.weights_}')

# Plot data points and gaussian components
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
if best_estimator.weight_concentration_prior_type == 'dirichlet_process':
  prior_label = 'Dirichlet process'
elif best_estimator.weight_concentration_prior_type == 'dirichlet_distribution':
  prior_label = 'Dirichlet distribution'

plot_results(X, best_estimator.means_, best_estimator.covariances_,
          f'Best Bayesian GMM | {prior_label} prior')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
plt.legend(fontsize='small')

# Plot histogram of weights
ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
for k, w in enumerate(best_estimator.weights_):
  plt.bar(k, w,
    width=0.9,
    color='#56B4E9',
    zorder=3,
    align='center',
    edgecolor='black'
    )
  plt.text(k, w + 0.01, "%.1f%%" % (w * 100.),
            horizontalalignment='center')
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out')
ax.yaxis.grid(True, alpha=0.7)
plt.xticks(range(len(best_estimator.weights_)))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=0.4)
plt.ylabel('Component weight')
plt.ylim(0, np.max(best_estimator.weights_)+0.25*np.max(best_estimator.weights_))
plt.yticks(())
plt.savefig('bgmm_clustering.png')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```